# Can Firebase users with verified emails be signed in anonymously?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

Our project used passwordless email verification to sign up new users. Due to proxy issues, we have elected to implement our own email verification workflow using Cloud Functions. This requires us to sign in users anonymously so they have a UID before sending them an email.

Will existing users, originally signed up through the out-of-the-box email verification workflow, automatically sign into their existing accounts if they sign in anonymously? Or will this create new users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only possible to sign in (anonymously or otherwise) if no user is signed in, and (as far as I know) there is no way to link an anonymous provider to an existing non-anonymous user account.

But if you sign the users in yourself with a custom provider, you can generate whatever UID you want already. There is nothing special about the ones Firebase generates, so any unique ID you come up with is going to be fine too.